# ¿Cómo solucionar errores de actualizacion de Debian?

Tags: linux, debian

Buen día, espero se encuentren bien, lamento molestaros en este post, pero llevo días intentando hacer una actualización en una distribución de Debian. Bueno, soy principiante en Linux, así que no sé si la terminología que estoy escribiendo sean las correctas; entonces, al ejecutar el comando: `sudo apt-get update` me salen los siguientes errores:

```
Err:1 http://mxrepo.com/mx/repo bullseye InRelease
No se pudo conectar a mxrepo.com:80 (70.40.214.183). - connect (101: La red es 
inaccesible)
Obj:2 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                              
Des:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 
kB]             
Obj:4 https://packages.sury.org/php bullseye InRelease                                             
Err:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                    
No se pudo conectar a packages.microsoft.com:80 (40.74.238.15). - connect (101: La 
red es inaccesible)
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                      
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                              
Err:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates Release                  
No se puede iniciar la conexión a deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:8a::644). - connect 
(101: La red es inaccesible)
Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye Release                          
No se puede iniciar la conexión a deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:8a::644). - connect 
(101: La red es inaccesible)
Des:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3 959 B]                                                                       
Obj:10 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                                                                                               
Obj:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease                                                                            
Des:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [344 
kB]                                                              
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                                                                                                                  
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates Release' no longer 
has a Release file.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto 
está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de 
repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye Release' no longer has a 
Release file.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto 
está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de 
repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Y esos son los errores que la verdad no tengo ni la menor idea de cómo solucionarlo. Si alguien tiene la molestia de decirme que me falta agregar o eliminar, se lo agradecería.

Comment: No parece que tengas conexión a la red. ¿Qué sucede si ejecutas `ping -c 3 debian.org`?